# C# Method Attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Is there a way to achieve this without injection? Topic is a UserControl. I am trying to check for Title and set it in Attribute.

```
public partial class Topic: TopicBase
{
[Topic(Title = "My Topic")]
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
base.OnInit(e);
}
}
```

When I look for the Attribute I get null in TopicBase.cs

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var topicAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType(), typeof(TopicAttribute)); //topicAttr is null here.
        if (topicAttr != null)
        {
            SetTopic(((TopicAttribute)topicAttr).Title);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for the attribute on your *type*. Your attribute sits on the *method*. Either change your query or put the attribute on the type as expected by your query:

```
[Topic(Title = "My Topic")]
public partial class Topic : TopicBase
{
}
```

Comment: What should the query be to check it on a method?

Comment: Calling the [same method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.attribute.getcustomattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) with a MemberInfo of your method should work.

Comment: Thanks. But when I try  Type clsType = typeof(Topic); MethodInfo mInfo = clsType.GetMethod("OnInit"); //mInfo is again null.

Answer (score 2):

As nvoigt said, you're trying to find the attributes of your class but you should use a MemberInfo of your method.

Something like that:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Topic).GetMethod("OnInit", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var attribute = methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TopicAttribute));
```

Comment: You will need to use `this.GetType()` instead of `typeof(Topic)`, because the OP wants to check the derived class method.

Comment: @nvoigt, oh, you're right, I just didn't realize that the second method is in a parent class, thanks :)